# Tomcat not starting : tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat8.5

[This is the error message i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9JJ3.png8)

I had tomcat8 already installed. i removed that and then i tried installing tomcat8 again but facing this issue and i am not able to install tomcat again.
List of Steps i followed before Installing -

1. `sudo apt-get remove tomcat8`
2. `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove tomcat8`
3. `sudo apt-get purge tomcat8`
4. `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove tomcat8`

Now i have installed new tomcat8 from here - https://websiteforstudents.com/setup-apache-tomcat-8-8-5-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-lts/

and getting error - image attached above

Comment: Please, add your error as text, not an image (cf. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11748454)).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are using Debian or Ubuntu, using the `tomcat8/tomcat9` packages (cf. [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/tomcat9)) is the easiest way to run a Tomcat server.

In your case the `tomcat.service` file lacks a [`PIDFile`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#PIDFile=) option, which helps determining in a reliable way that Tomcat is running. Therefore I would modify your `tomcat.service` script to contain:

```txt
[Service]
# ...
# The rest of the options
PIDFile="/run/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/run/tomcat.pid"
```

Before starting the service make sure that your Tomcat is not running (`killall java` or something more subtle) and remember to reload the SystemD daemon:

```sh
systemctl daemon-reload
```

**Edit:** After the modification the `tomcat.service` file should look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat servlet container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/run/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

PIDFile="/run/tomcat.pid"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What needs to be modified?,
Below is my tomcat.service content

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom"

Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: I added the entire `tomcat.service` file to the answer.

Comment: Didn't work after this too, pasting error below -

startup.sh[12026]: Tomcat started.

systemd[1]: Started Tomcat servlet container.

shutdown.sh[12089]: $CATALINA_PID was set but the specified file does not exist. Is Tomcat running? Stop aborte

systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:19: Not an absolute path, ignoring: "/run/tomcat.pid"

Comment: Check Tomcat's logs to see why the server startup fails.

Answer (score 0):

In my case using RHEL 8 system and i did below steps to fix the issue, then able to start tomcat service using systemctl.

**Step 1:** Validate any SELinux context related error in the audit search.

ausearch -m avc -ts recent

error reported unable to start service using systemctl due to SELinux context.

**Step 2:** Change SELinux SELinux contex for tomcat related files and directories

```
ls -lZ /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service
chcon system_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0 /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service
chcon -Rv system_u:object_r:etc_runtime_t:s0 /opt/CAE/
semanage fcontext -a -t etc_runtime_t /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
semanage fcontext -a -t etc_runtime_t /opt/CAE/
```

**Step 3:** Define the systemctl file with below information's

```
$ sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tomcat.service
[Unit]
Description=tomcat service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat


Environment="JAVA_HOME=/opt/CAE/CAESECURE_CMVQ1Z02_AS/java"
Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/CAE/CAESECURE_CMVQ1Z02_AS/tomcat"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/CAE/CAESECURE_CMVQ1Z02_AS/tomcat"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat.pid"
PIDFile="/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat.pid"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Step 4:** Now start the service using systemctl

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start tomcat.service
systemctl restart tomcat.service
```

**Validation:** Now no SELinux error has been reported and able to start the service

```
ausearch -m avc -ts recent
systemctl status tomcat.service
```

no error reported