# PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current user does not have permission to stop the process

Tags: java, tomcat, startup, pid, tomcat9

I'm facing a problem with Apache Tomcat 9.0.50, Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS and Java JDK 8.

I am not able to start Tomcat9 as a service, because if I check its status after started, it shows the error: **PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current user does not have permission to stop the process. Stop aborted.**

I've created a dedicated group and user for Tomcat (group tomcat9, user tomcat9).

If I check the ps (process-show) Linux tool, for example with:

```
ps -faux | grep tomcat
```

Tomcat is not present, so the process is not active.

I'm running **sudo systemctl start tomcat.service**

with the "sadmin" account that belongs to sudoers and also belongs to tomcat9 group.

```
Jul 06 17:14:55 i-s-023 systemd[1]: Starting Tomcat9...
Jul 06 17:14:55 i-s-023 startup.sh[5257]: Existing PID file found during start.
Jul 06 17:14:55 i-s-023 startup.sh[5257]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
Jul 06 17:14:55 i-s-023 startup.sh[5257]: Tomcat started.
Jul 06 17:14:55 i-s-023 shutdown.sh[5279]: PID file found but either no matching process was found or the current user does not have permission to stop the process. Stop aborted.
Jul 06 17:14:55 i-s-023 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 06 17:14:55 i-s-023 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 06 17:14:55 i-s-023 systemd[1]: Failed to start Tomcat9.
```

Here it is my **/opt** folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root    root        4096 Jul  6 14:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root    root        4096 Jun 24 01:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 tomcat9 tomcat9     4096 Jul  6 16:43 apache-tomcat-9.0.50
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root    11507318 Jun 28 10:52 apache-tomcat-9.0.50.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x  7 root    root        4096 Jul  6 16:34 jdk1.8.0_221
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root          20 Jul  6 14:44 tomcat-latest -> apache-tomcat-9.0.50
```

Those are permissions inside **/opt/tomcat-latest** folder

```
drwxr-xr-x 9 tomcat9 tomcat9  4096 Jul  6 16:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root    root     4096 Jul  6 14:44 ..
drwxrwx--- 2 root    tomcat9  4096 Jul  6 14:44 bin
-rw-r----- 1 root    tomcat9 18949 Jun 28 10:46 BUILDING.txt
drwxr-x--- 2 root    tomcat9  4096 Jun 28 10:46 conf
-rw-r----- 1 root    tomcat9  6210 Jun 28 10:46 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxr-x--- 2 root    tomcat9  4096 Jul  6 14:44 lib
-rw-r----- 1 root    tomcat9 57092 Jun 28 10:46 LICENSE
drwxr-x--- 2 tomcat9 tomcat9  4096 Jul  6 14:46 logs
-rw-r----- 1 root    tomcat9  2333 Jun 28 10:46 NOTICE
-rw-r----- 1 root    tomcat9  3372 Jun 28 10:46 README.md
-rw-r----- 1 root    tomcat9  6898 Jun 28 10:46 RELEASE-NOTES
-rw-r----- 1 root    tomcat9 16507 Jun 28 10:46 RUNNING.txt
drwxr-x--- 2 tomcat9 tomcat9  4096 Jul  6 17:14 temp
drwxr-x--- 7 tomcat9 tomcat9  4096 Jun 28 10:46 webapps
drwxr-x--- 2 tomcat9 tomcat9  4096 Jun 28 10:46 work
```

The service is defined as shown below:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat9
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=tomcat9
Group=tomcat9
WorkingDirectory=/opt/tomcat-latest/bin
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat-latest/temp/tomcat9.pid
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_221
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat-latest
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat-latest
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms1280m -Xmx3840m"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dnet.sf.ehcache.skipUpdateCheck=true -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseParNewGC  -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDec$

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat-latest/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat-latest/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Do you have any advice?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you install Tomcat with apt?

Comment: You have the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67253906/11748454): you didn't specify the PIDFile property so SystemD does not know where to find it.

Comment: Find the process with `pgrep -af 'java .*catalina.startup.Bootstrap'` or `ps -lf -C 'java' | grep '.*catalina.startup.Bootstrap'`

Comment: @g00se No, I've just downloaded the tar.gz version of Tomcat, then extracted to /opt folder and created the tomcat.service file.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thanks for your answer, I'll give a try and I'll let you know :)

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using the package manager

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the Environment points to existing path. In my case JAVA_HOME was set to non existent java.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue short time ago.My problem was systemd unit file was addressing wrong arch java.Changed JAVA_HOME and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with permission granted, java installed, JAVA_HOME correctly configured.

Solved it by adding a "" at the ExecStart and ExecStop path

```
ExecStart="/opt/tomcat-latest/bin/startup.sh"
ExecStop="/opt/tomcat-latest/bin/shutdown.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error message, while addressing a Java installation that was installed using sdkman and was installed under `/root`, hence being not accessible for the `tomcat` user.

I solved it by installing sdkman as user `tomcat` and then installing the same Java version in a directory that was accessible by `tomcat`. Last, I changed the path in my service file, of course.